# ViewerJS, S3 and CORS - load resource from different S3 bucket/domain

Tags: amazon-s3, cors

I have two S3 buckets.

- `my-js-bucket` has the ViewerJS library files
- `my-file-bucket` has the files I want to view

I added the following to the CORS for my-file-bucket:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

When I try to load the page, eg:

`https://my-js-bucket.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/ViewerJS/index.html#https://my-file-bucket.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/logo.png`

I get CORS errors in the console.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All I had to do is add "HEAD" to the AllowedMethods.

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```